# Navegacion entre paginas en Vuetify

Tags: vuetify

Buenas amigos soy nuevo en esta comunidad,queria ver si me podrian ayudar sobre el framework Vuetify soy nuevo utilizando esta tecnología, mi pregunta es como puede hacer para navegar entre paginas desde un menu layout, he investigado sobre como se hace con la configuracion desde el archivo router pero no logro que me funcione, les dejo el codigo de mi plantilla...
------este archivo es un .js -----

```
export default {

  // home is a section without childs, set as an empty array
  home: [],

  categorias: [

    {
      type: 'title',
      txt: 'Productos',
      icon: 'fa fa-cart-plus',
    },

    {
      type: 'link',
      txt: 'Listado de Productos',
      link: '/page',
    },

    {
      type: 'link',
      txt: 'Agregar Productos',

      link: '/page',
    },

    {
      type:'link',
      txt: 'Gestionar Categorias',
      link: '/page',
    },

  ],

  ventas: [

    {
      type: 'title',
      txt: 'Nueva venta',
      icon: 'fa fa-users context-menu__title-icon',
    },

    {
      type: 'link',
      txt: 'Anulacion de Venta',
      link: '/page',
    },

    {
      type: 'link',
      txt: 'Nueva venta',
      link: '/page',
    },

    {
      type: 'link',
      txt: 'Venta pendientes',
      link: '/page',
    },

  ],
};
```

ese codigo es el que forma mi menu quisiera saber si desde ahi puedo mandar a llamar una pagina .vue por ejemplo la pagina categoria.vue

```
 {
      type: 'link',
      txt: 'Venta pendientes',
      router: '../components/categoria.vue' //por decir asi pero esa 
                propiedad router no me funciona 
      link: '/page',
    },
```

si alguien me podria sacar de esa duda se lo agradeceria...

Comment: Si estas trabajando con el CLI de VUE, te recomiendo leer la documentación ya que prácticamente no tienes nada hecho https://router.vuejs.org/ otra recomendación es hacer algún curso si no eres de leer mucho https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAQB7Y4X5fM&list=PLPl81lqbj-4J-gfAERGDCdOQtVgRhSvIT

Comment: Pues eso estado viendo, solo que los curso ya son un poco antiguos y vuetify como que ha sacado una nueva versión y han cambiado bastante la sintaxis de algunas etiquetas y yo en mi proyecto tengo la ultima version... Igual gracias por las recomendaciones...